# Accessing another view controller's function

Tags: iphone

I need to access another view controller's function from a modal view,
but the problem is, the view controller being called is not a parent controller of the modal view which calls it. So I cannot use self.parentViewController.
I'm currently using the following, but it crashes.

```
in the modal view,
#include "mainViewController.h"

..........

        MainViewController* mainView;
        mainView = (MainViewController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [mainView reset:(id)sender];
```

Any idea what's wrong?
Please help me.

Comment: In most cases notifications, as Kobski suggests, will be a better way to go. If an instance of MainViewController already exists why create another one? If the function depends on ivars that relate to the particular instance creating a new may give you the wrong results. On the other hand, if it doesn't depend on ivars you could put the function in a class method instead.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment really belongs under dudeUser's answer. The approach above is OK, even if notifications is often better. Did you try logging to see what mainView was pointing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
   MainViewController* mainView;
   mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
   [mainView reset:(id)sender];
```

Answer (score 2):

The modal view controller should not need to know about the main view controller. Instead use notifications and send a notification from the modal view controller. Listen to this notification in the main view controller or the application delegate.

Here is the official introduction from Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html